# combine columns with different length by id in r

Tags: r, merge

I have two data sets which contains common "id" variable.

```
dat1=data.frame(id = rep(1:3,3), 
                var1 = c(1:9),var2=(11:19)) 
dat2=data.frame(id= c(1:3), var3=(2:4), var4=(50:52))
```

What I'm going to do is combine var1 and var4 with respect to id.  So the final data set should be like as follow.

```
dat3=cbind(dat1, var4=c(50,50,50,51,51,51,52,52,52))
```

I think `merge` function cannot combine columns. 
Is there any function I can get dat3 simply?

Comment: Have you tried `merge(dat1, dat2, by = 'id', all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just noticed that the `merge` output is not similar to the expected output.  So, it is not a dupe.